# GRASS v.buffer.column and v.buffer.distance - Incomplete Output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer

I have tried .column and .distance buffers within QGIS and both are leaving me with incomplete results. Only a few of the features within my input file are actually being buffered.

[image]

I also have both "Make outside corners straight" and "Don't make caps at the ends of polylines" set to 'No'

Why is this occuring?

Comment: Were any features selected before you ran the tool? If so, make sure you **unselect all features** and try buffering again.

Comment: Nope, I've tried it multiple times

Comment: Perhaps they contain geometric errors? You could try running the **Geometry Checker** plugin. Have you tested the layer with the QGIS buffer tool to see if that buffers all lines?

Comment: I think I have solved the issue. If I only have "Don't make caps..." set as yes, the entire layer will buffer. It just doesn't work if "Make outside corners straight" is also checked. I have finally got the output I require, however is there any way to have an un-dissolved buffer? Aka. one polygon per original polyline

Comment: Awesome, glad you got what you needed! You should post what you did as an **answer**. The `Fixed distance buffer` and `Variable distance buffer` allows you to make un-dissolved buffers.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to have an un-dissolved, but still uncapped end buffer?

Comment: Don't think so. Just a thought but if you buffer your layer with both GRASS and QGIS and then use the **Clip** tool on the outputs, you might get what you're looking for.